# Combinations with repetition with limits.

Tags: combinations

From a Standard 52 card deck of playing cards.
If 10 hands are dealt consisting of 2 cards each what is the probability of 3 of the hands being pairs? 4? 5? ....

Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$\frac{52!}{2!^{10}}$$ 
is the number of ways to select 10 sets 2 cards each. Can you handle from here?

Comment: We need to draw only 20 cards....

Comment: '10 sets 2 cards each'= 20 cards

Comment: 52! means dealing *all* the cards, but only 20 are needed

Comment: Use multinomial identity

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

How many ranks are there ?

Choose 3 ranks, and pairs from them.

How many cards remain of a rank other than those of the pairs chosen ?

Choose 7 hands with 2 "singles" each from them

---

$$\text{Favorable ways =}{13\choose3}{4\choose2}^3{10\choose 7}{4\choose1}^7$$

$$\text{Total ways =}\frac{{52\choose20}\cdot20!}{10!\cdot(2!)^{10}}$$

Divide to get the probability and work out similarly for 4,5 pairs